# RDD persist mechanism （what happen when I persist a RDD and then use take(10) not count() ）

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

what happens when I persist a RDD and then use take(10) instead of count().
I have read some comments, it says that if I use take() instead of count, it might only persist partial partition not all the partitions.
But, if my dataset is big enough，then using count is very time consuming.
Is there any other action operator that I can use to trigger persist to persist all partition.

foreachPartition is an action operator and it need data from all partitions, can I use this after persist?

need your help ~

Ex:

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile("src/main/resources/").persist()
rdd1.foreachPartition(partition=>partition.take(1))
```

Comment: You don't need to force the persistence of the RDD. It will be persisted when you call an action later in your code.

Comment: Yes, that's ture, but in my scenario, memory is not big enough, so I need to force the persistence of the RDD and unpersist it when I do not need it. Wating for GC clean those RDD is wasting memory. That's why I want to force the persistence of the RDD.